# Querying unmapped properties in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, linq-to-nhibernate

I am working with Linq-To-NHibernate. I need to use some properties that is not mapped to columns.

For example

```
Repository<Person>
   .Find()
   .Select(p => new PersonModel() { Id = p.Id, FullName= p.FullName,Position = p.Position });
```

The position is not a mapped property, it contains some logic.
I got unmapped property error.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65288396/how-do-i-get-nhibernate-to-generate-sql-for-a-computed-property/65302675#65302675

Answer (score 4):

Not possible, and not likely to be supported in short term.