# How do I get NHibernate to generate SQL for a computed property?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I've Googled around and come up with sample code, but it's giving me trouble.  Here's what I've got, based on what I found:

In the persistent class I have

```
public static readonly Expression<Func<Detail, decimal>> TotExpression = d =>
    (decimal)((d.Fee == null ? 0 : d.Fee) + (d.Expenses == null ? 0 : d.Expenses));

public static Func<Detail, decimal> CompiledTot => TotExpression.Compile();
public virtual decimal Tot => CompiledTot(this);
```

I register the property using

```
class ComputedPropertyGeneratorRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public ComputedPropertyGeneratorRegistry()
    {
        CalculatedPropertyGenerator<Detail, decimal>.Register(
            this,
            x => x.Tot,
            Detail.TotExpression);
    }
}

public class CalculatedPropertyGenerator<T, TResult> : BaseHqlGeneratorForProperty
{
    public static void Register(ILinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry registry, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> property, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> calculationExp)
    {
        registry.RegisterGenerator(ReflectHelper.GetProperty(property), new CalculatedPropertyGenerator<T, TResult> { _calculationExp = calculationExp });
    }
    private CalculatedPropertyGenerator() { } // Private constructor

    private Expression<Func<T, TResult>> _calculationExp;
    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MemberInfo member, Expression expression, HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        return visitor.Visit(_calculationExp);
    }
}
```

And in my session-factory configuration I have

```
cfg.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<ComputedPropertyGeneratorRegistry>();
```

Yet when I run

```
session.Query<Detail>().Select(x => x.Tot).First();
```

I get

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'd.Fee'
```

It seems that when NH tries to generate the SQL it calls, at some point, `LiteralProcessor.LookupConstant` on `d.Fee`, which calls `ReflectHelper.GetConstantValue("d.Fee")`, which for some reason assumes that "d" is the name of the class to which the property belongs.  Of course it isn't, which breaks everything.  I have no idea why it's going down this wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem seems to be that the HQL generator returns an expression where the 'd' parameter isn't treated as a parameter, so the resultant HQL doesn't know what to do with it.  If I change the 'x' parameter in my query to 'd', as in

```
session.Query<Detail>().Select(d => d.Tot).First();
```

it all hangs together.  This is obviously a bother, but not enough of one to outweigh being able to search on and select computed properties.  I assume someone who understands the HQL "visitor" better would be able to make the proper adjustments in the HQL generator, but I'll leave that for some other volunteer.

**UPDATE**:  I couldn't leave it at that, so I cobbled together a way to do it, with the help of some code from [Phil Klein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115650/phil-klein).

Phil's provided this class

```
public class PredicateRewriter
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> Rewrite<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> exp, string newParamName)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(exp.Parameters[0].Type, newParamName);
        var newExpression = new PredicateRewriterVisitor(param).Visit(exp);

        return (Expression<Func<T, TResult>>)newExpression;
    }

    private class PredicateRewriterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly ParameterExpression _parameterExpression;

        public PredicateRewriterVisitor(ParameterExpression parameterExpression)
        {
            _parameterExpression = parameterExpression;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return _parameterExpression;
        }
    }
}
```

which I use here

```
    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MemberInfo member, Expression expression, HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        // this is a kludge because I don't know how to pry the name out of the parameter expression
        var inside = new Regex("\\[(.*)\\]");
        var name = inside.Match(expression.ToString()).Groups[1].Value;
        return visitor.Visit(PredicateRewriter.Rewrite<T, TResult>(_calculationExp, name));
    }
```

It's not going to work if the expression has multiple parameters, but that rarely happens and I'm really not looking to make a career of refining this :).

**UPDATE**:  I have a resolution.  Rather than subclassing `DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry`, which seems to be too far down the chain of converting LINQ to SQL, I subclassed `DefaultQueryProvider, IQueryProviderWithOptions` and inserted it with `cfg.LinqQueryProvider<CustomQueryProvider>()`.

This is based on code from [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134101/custom-linqtohqlgeneratorsregistry-invalidcastexception-unable-cast-antlr-r/56245218#56245218).